# Get type of custom class from the string [Swift, Spritekit]

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a game script file, which contains names of chapters and/or names of games in it. I am presenting the next scene automatically using this function:

```
func presentScene(from: SKScene, model: SceneModel)
    {
        gamestate.update(scene: model)
        soundboard.pause(fadeDuration: 1)

        switch model.type
        {
        case .game(let name, _, _):
            if let game = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") as? GameScene {
                game.model = model
                from.view?.presentScene(game, transition: SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.6))
            }

        case .text(_):
            if let text = SKScene(fileNamed: "TextScene") as? TextScene {
                text.model = model
                from.view?.presentScene(text, transition: SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.6))
            }

        case .video(_, _, _):
            if let video = SKScene(fileNamed: "VideoScene") as? VideoScene {
                video.model = model
                from.view?.presentScene(video, transition: SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.6))
            }
        }
    }
```

So my question is this: can I get a type of custom game class using string variable? Like this

```
let nameString = "dakjsdljk"    
if let game = SKScene(fileNamed: nameString) as? nameString {

    }
```

or the only way to do it is creating an enum with game types and initialising it's values from raw string manually ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: From what I can tell, your casting is not needed at all.  Just make the `model.type` the string version of the sks you want to load, and you can eliminate the branching.  `if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: model.type) {
                scene.model = model
                from.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.6))
            }`

Comment: @Knight0fDragon if I don't cast scene as GameScene (or any else custom scene I use in the game), I won't be able to access model variable

Comment: use a protocol,  that is what it is designed for.  Model is needed across 3 different types

Comment: I doubt model is even needed, you probably could infer it